# how to sum corresponding values?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Input xml format:

```
a.xml
<Global>
  <CurrencyType>INR</CurrencyType>
  <Amount>100.56</Amount>
</Global>

b.xml
<Global>
  <CurrencyType>USD</CurrencyType>
  <Amount>234.45</Amount>
</Global>

c.xml
<Global>
  <CurrencyType>INR</CurrencyType>
  <Amount>20</Amount>
</Global>

d.xml
<Global>
  <CurrencyType>EUR</CurrencyType>
  <Amount>450.0</Amount>
</Global>

e.xml
<Global>
  <CurrencyType>DIR</CurrencyType>
  <Amount>100.56</Amount>
</Global>
```

I have used `cts:sum` query to add the Amount values for various currency type. Currency values other than **INR & USD** is modified as **OTH** as given below:

```
let $doc := all the xml files 
for $currency in fn:distinct-values($doc//CurrencyType) 
let $tot := cts:sum(cts:element-values(xs:QName('Amount'),(),(),
                      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('Currency'),$currency))) 
return  if($currency eq ('INR','USD'))  then concat($tot, " ", $currency)  
        else concat($tot, " ", 'OTH')
```

that gives the following output

> 120.56 INR
>
> 234.45 USD
>
> 450.0 OTH
>
> 100.0 OTH

Now, I need to sum up the values that has same currency values. I need to add 450.0 + 100.0 that is to get the total amount of other currency values.

Could anyone help on this?

Comment: What is your exact input format? Is it a single string, XML data, or something completely different? And how should the output look like?

Comment: Is MarkLogic 9 an option?  If not, what version of MarkLogic?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Jim and Mads, avoid `distinct-values`. Particularly since `cts:element-values` requires a range index anyhow. I'd also avoid using `cts:sum` (which is officially deprecated by the way), and use the more performant [`cts:sum-aggregate`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:sum-aggregate) instead. I'd consider Jim's approach, and do something like:

```
let $currencies := cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("CurrencyType")))
let $explicit-currencies := $currencies[. = ("INR", "USD")]
let $other-currencies := $currencies[not(. = $explicit-currencies)]
return (
  for $c in $explicit-currencies
  let $sum := cts:sum-aggregate(
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("Amount")),
    (),
    cts:range-query(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("CurrencyType")), "=", $c)
  )
  return $c || " " || $sum,

  let $other-sum := cts:sum-aggregate(
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("Amount")),
    (),
    cts:range-query(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("CurrencyType")), "=", $other-currencies)
  )
  return "OTH" || " " || $other-sum
)
```

Note: `cts:range-query` is new in MarkLogic 9. You can use `cts:element-range-query` in older versions instead.

You could shorten above code even further, and literally do as Jim suggests:

```
let $explicit-currencies := ("INR", "USD")
return (
  for $c in $explicit-currencies
  let $sum := cts:sum-aggregate(
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("Amount")),
    (),
    cts:range-query(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("CurrencyType")), "=", $c)
  )
  return $c || " " || $sum,

  let $other-sum := cts:sum-aggregate(
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("Amount")),
    (),
    cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("CurrencyType"), $explicit-currencies))
  )
  return "OTH" || " " || $other-sum
)
```

The latter would not require a range index on `CurrencyType`, but if you have that exposed as facet, you probably have that anyhow.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

`distinct-values()` can be a very expensive call.

For your problem, you also don't need it.

Just do 3 queries - one for INR, one for USD, and the other for `cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('CurrencyType'), ("INR","USD")))`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many documents "all of the XML files" is, loading all of those documents and XPathing to the `CurrencyType`, and the using `distinct-values()` could be expensive and slow.

Instead, you could:

1. obtain a distinct list of `CurrencyType` and `Amount` values for those documents using `cts:element-value-co-occurences()` and return the results as a Map.
2. iterate over each of the Map entries and normalize the `CurrencyType` and add up all of the `Amount` values for the normalized `CurrencyType` label
3. then print out the totals.

---

```
 (: 1. obtain the CurrencyType and Amount values as a map :)
let $currencyMap := cts:element-value-co-occurrences(
                      xs:QName("CurrencyType"), 
                      xs:QName("Amount"), 
                      "map", 
                      (:change this to a more specific query for "all the xml files" :)
                      cts:true-query())
let $totalMap := map:map()
return 
( 
  for $currency in map:keys($currencyMap)
 (: 2.a. normalize the labels :)
  let $label := 
      if ($currency = ('INR', 'USD')) then $currency 
      else "OTH"
  return
 (: 2.b. as we iterate through each CurrencyType, add it's Amount to the current total :)
    map:put($totalMap, $label, 
            sum((map:get($currencyMap, $currency), map:get($totalMap, $label))) ),
 (: 3. Print out the totals for the consolidated currency labels :) 
  map:keys($totalMap) ! concat(map:get($totalMap, .), " ", .)
)
```